# Reading a LP file with binary variables with GLPK

Tags: java, optimization, solver

I am trying to read a very simple LP file into GLPK. This LP file has 4 variables of which 2 are binary, and seems that GLPK reads badly these 2 binary variables (HACE_MESAS, HACE_SILLAS). It logs:

> warning: lower bound of variable HACE_MESAS redefined warning: upper
>   bound of variable HACE_MESAS redefined warning: lower bound of
>   variable HACE_SILLAS redefined warning: upper bound of variable
>   HACE_SILLAS redefined

and it solves badly because puts real values to these two variables:

```
HACE_MESAS = 0.01
HACE_SILLAS = 0.02
```

The LP file is like this:

```
Maximize
 obj: 5 MESAS + 3 SILLAS
Subject To
 IloC0: MESAS + 2 SILLAS >= 0
 IloC1: MESAS + 2 SILLAS <= 50
 IloC2: 2 MESAS + SILLAS >= 0
 IloC3: 2 MESAS + SILLAS <= 40
 IloC4: MESAS - 1000 HACE_MESAS <= 0
 IloC5: SILLAS - 1000 HACE_SILLAS <= 0
 IloC6: HACE_MESAS + HACE_SILLAS <= 1
Bounds
      MESAS >= 0
      SILLAS >= 0
 0 <= HACE_MESAS <= 1
 0 <= HACE_SILLAS <= 1
Binaries
 HACE_MESAS  HACE_SILLAS 
Generals
 MESAS  SILLAS 
End
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing bad? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the redundant bounds (they are unnecessary but as you see cause trouble)

```
 0 <= HACE_MESAS <= 1
 0 <= HACE_SILLAS <= 1
```

That is, I run this model:

```
Maximize
 obj: 5 MESAS + 3 SILLAS
Subject To
 IloC0: MESAS + 2 SILLAS >= 0
 IloC1: MESAS + 2 SILLAS <= 50
 IloC2: 2 MESAS + SILLAS >= 0
 IloC3: 2 MESAS + SILLAS <= 40
 IloC4: MESAS - 1000 HACE_MESAS <= 0
 IloC5: SILLAS - 1000 HACE_SILLAS <= 0
 IloC6: HACE_MESAS + HACE_SILLAS <= 1
Bounds
      MESAS >= 0
      SILLAS >= 0
Binaries
 HACE_MESAS  HACE_SILLAS 
Generals
 MESAS  SILLAS 
End
```

Everything works as expected:

```
Problem:    
Rows:       7
Columns:    4 (4 integer, 2 binary)
Non-zeros:  14
Status:     INTEGER OPTIMAL
Objective:  obj = 100 (MAXimum)

   No.   Row name        Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound
------ ------------    ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 IloC0                      20             0               
     2 IloC1                      20                          50 
     3 IloC2                      40             0               
     4 IloC3                      40                          40 
     5 IloC4                    -980                           0 
     6 IloC5                       0                           0 
     7 IloC6                       1                           1 

   No. Column name       Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound
------ ------------    ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 MESAS        *             20             0               
     2 SILLAS       *              0             0               
     3 HACE_MESAS   *              1             0             1 
     4 HACE_SILLAS  *              0             0             1 

Integer feasibility conditions:

KKT.PE: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        High quality

KKT.PB: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        High quality

End of output
```

Comment: Yes, but if you see the solution: HACE_MESAS and HACE_SILLAS have real solutions and not only 0 or 1. HACE_MESAS = 0.01
HACE_SILLAS = 0.02

Comment: @user2107157 I have updated my answer: **everything** is integer. Please check what I have done and try to reproduce my steps on your machine.